Can't ping my host from a CentOS linux server although I can ssh to the linux server
After creating a CentOS server using Hyper-V on my Windows 10 host. I set up an internal switch to allow communication between the host and the VM.
The problem is that I can't ping the host from the VM although I can ping the VM from the host. I can ssh to the VM normally from the host and the VM can use curl to request files from the host.
I have tried to allow ICMP traffic (ping) but it didn't work
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-icmp-block=echo-request --permanent
I have also tried tcpdump -i eth1 to check if the request passes and I found this output when pinging from the linux server to the host
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
07:44:57.073024 IP 10.0.0.1.55466 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 175
07:44:58.086894 IP 10.0.0.1.55466 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 175
07:44:59.087701 IP 10.0.0.1.55466 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 175
07:45:00.100374 IP 10.0.0.1.55466 > 239.255.255.250.ssdp: UDP, length 175
07:45:10.481566 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 10, seq 1, length 64
07:45:11.497575 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 10, seq 2, length 64
07:45:12.521623 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 10, seq 3, length 64
07:45:13.545307 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 10, seq 4, length 64
07:45:15.657420 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.1 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
07:45:15.667394 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.1 is-at 00:15:5d:dc:19:58 (oui Unknown), length 28

And I got this output when pinging from the host to the server
07:45:37.455817 IP 10.0.0.1 > localhost.localdomain: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14420, length 40
07:45:37.455896 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 14420, length 40
07:45:38.471134 IP 10.0.0.1 > localhost.localdomain: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14422, length 40
07:45:38.471210 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 14422, length 40
07:45:39.485028 IP 10.0.0.1 > localhost.localdomain: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14424, length 40
07:45:39.485139 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 14424, length 40
07:45:40.499389 IP 10.0.0.1 > localhost.localdomain: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14426, length 40
07:45:40.499509 IP localhost.localdomain > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 14426, length 40
07:45:42.030437 ARP, Request who-has localhost.localdomain (00:15:5d:dc:19:b5 (oui Unknown)) tell 10.0.0.1, length 28
07:45:42.030453 ARP, Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 00:15:5d:dc:19:b5 (oui Unknown), length 28
07:45:42.793369 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.1 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
07:45:42.796372 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.1 is-at 00:15:5d:dc:19:58 (oui Unknown), length 28

The problem doesn't affect me too much as I can freely ssh to the server and the server can freely curl data from the host, but I want to know the cause of this.

I would suspect a firewall or config issue on the Win10 host.  You could install ethereal (aka wireshark) on the windows machine and snoop traffic from that end.  Or, just for testing purposes, disable the windows firewall and disable the linux firewall.

it was the problem.
thanks for helping
